# Need explanation for the chronological order of the avatars of Lord Vishnu in Shreemad Bhagavata Mahapurana.?

Tags: rama, avatars, bhagavata-purana, vyasa, explanation

Why Shreemad Bhagavata Mahapurana says that Krishna Dwaipayana Veda Vyasa who is the son of Satyavati and Rishi Parashara appeared before Shree Rama in [Skanda 1 Chapter 3](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/1/3/).?